# Path VS Shape in Paperjs?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, paperjs

I have an interesting issue with the Paperjs library. The behaviour of polygon created by path's is very different from the behaviour of objects created by shape. The path object when applied with a Rotation treats it like a ninja star while the motion I desire is perfectly done.

Here are the fiddle links for each of the cases.

```
Path.Rectangle({
   center: [0, 0],
   size: [40, 40],
   fillColor: 'white'
});
```

[Path fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chxfwgh7/)

```
Shape.Rectangle({
   center: [0, 0],
   size: [40, 40],
   fillColor: 'white'
});
```

[Shape fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chxfwgh7/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, transforms are applied directly to a `path` object, not stored in the item's `Matrix`. This is controlled by the [`applyMatrix` property](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#applymatrix). You can change this behavior globally by adding:

```
settings.applyMatrix = false;
```

to your paperscript, or on the item level with:

```
this.head = new Path.Rectangle({
    center: [0, 0],
    size: [40, 40],
    fillColor: 'white',
    applyMatrix: false
});
```

Comment: Ironically if I use javascript instead of paperscript, this implementation doesn't work.

Comment: It should, provided that you're declaring your scope properly. Do you have an example?

Comment: I will try and condense the code to recreate the situation for a small set of data. But this is the error I get `Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function`. I realize how vague this error is, so here is the place it breaks with this error which I use `this.head = new Path.Rectangle({ ...`. It's at `this.applyMatrix(true)` is not a function

Comment: Okay just figured my paper is version `v0.9.15`

Comment: The example is in `v0.9.21` ironically it breaks if I upgrade the versions

Comment: Yep resolved the issue. Your answer was  a great starting point +1